# How do I call a function by string without using reflection?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write something that calls a function at runtime without using reflection.

Below is my attempt that doesn't work D:

```
 public delegate void FunctionPointer(string t);

 public void UseFunctionPointer(string t)
    {
        FunctionPointer pointer = t;
        t();
    }
```

I realize I can use a giant switch or if/else to match them, but I want to keep the code clean.

can someone point me to the right direction? 
or tell me "it is impossible"

Comment: Wow is that code horribly wrong in so many ways... `FunctionPointer` requires a string parameter in it's call, you're attempting to implicitly convert a string into a function, and then you are attempting to call the string t as a method?

Comment: Also, why is it important to avoid reflection when it is useful in your situation?

Comment: medium trust servers restrict the access to the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionary of functions by name could be an option:

```
var functions = new Dictionary<string, Func<float, float>>();
functions.Add("sqr", x=>x*x);

Console.WriteLine(functions["sqr"](3));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use delegates if you want your method to execute different functions.

This way you can pass in an implementation of your choosing, and still be strongly typed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use expressions and create a cache of them, something like this:

```
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<Type, string>, Action> MethodCache =
    new ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<Type, string>, Action>();

public static void Run<T>(string method)
{
    // Calls static parameterless methods on any type

    var act = MethodCache.GetOrAdd(
        Tuple.Create(typeof (T), method),
        v =>
            {
                var mi = v.Item1.GetMethod(
                    v.Item2, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                return (Action) Expression.Lambda(Expression.Call(mi)).Compile();
            });

    act();
}
```

Comment: This uses reflection, which the OP did not want to use. The only difference is you're using caching.